# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call `Realm.init(Context)` before calling this method

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-database

Хочу сохранить данные в базу данных Realm:

```
 Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(user);
                    realm.cancelTransaction();
```

Получаю ошибку: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call`Realm.init(Context)`before calling this method`

Что не так? Как исправить?

Comment: С версии realm 2.* разработчики применили [новый механизм инициализации  БД](https://realm.io/news/realm-java-2-0-mobile-platform-support/) (раздел Global initializer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Инициализируйте Realm прежде чем работать с ней.

```
Realm.init(Context);
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(user);
                    realm.cancelTransaction();
```